# If you roll a 1 on a saving throw against a damage spell, do you take extra damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw, fumbles

For example:

> **Fireball** Each creature must make a DEX saving throw. A target takes 8d6 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a
>   successful one.

If a target caught in the fireball rolls a 1 on their saving throw, which is an automatic fail, does the target take any form of extra damage?

Comment: Related questions here [1](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90860/225660), [2](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/53119/22566) , [3](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/81218/22566) , and [4](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63427/22566).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### No extra damage is taken

Saving throw for *fireball* is "pass/fail".

> 3. Compare the total to a target number. If the total equals or exceeds the target number, the ability check, attack roll, or saving throw is a success. Otherwise, it’s a failure. The DM is usually the one who determines target numbers and tells players whether their ability checks, attack rolls, and saving throws succeed or fail (page 4, Basic Rules)

#### "which is an automatic fail"  (there isn't one)

There is no specific rule in this edition for a d20 result of 20 or 1 on a saving throw -- except the specific rule for *the death saving throw* when a PC is at 0 HP.  (See below; Basic Rules p. 76).  Without a *specific rule* like that for *fireball*, the *general rule* for saving throws is how it works.

A missed save is a missed save.  The damage for a save is per the spell description.   *Fireball's* spell description does not call for boosted damage due to a given result on the saving throw.   Damage is whatever comes up on the damage dice rolled; damage is halved if the save is made.

Saving Throws (Basic Rules, p. 62)(Chapter 7)

> The result of a successful or failed saving throw is also detailed in
>   the effect that allows the save. Usually, a successful save means that
>   a creature suffers no harm, or reduced harm, from an effect.

#### What about Criticals?

A Critical hit (20 on a d20) and an automatic miss (1 on a d20) are confined to **spell attacks** and **weapon attacks** that require **an attack roll**.  The *fireball* spell does not require an attack roll, it only requires a saving throw.  The 1 rolled on the saving throw is as good as the 13 if the save required was a 14: it is a failed save (no modification to damage done).

- The DM can use the die roll as a cue on how the failed save is described during play.  A low roll might be described as "you are caught squarely by a burst of flame" while a roll that "just missed" could be described as "you try to dodge but your wounds slowed you down just enough to catch the full heat of the fireball."  How a DM describes the events in combat can add a lot to the game, regardless of the mechanical pass/fail points.

#### What automatic fail?

- For a spell cast with a low DC against a creature with a substantial saving throw bonus (let's say a proficiency bonus of +6 and another bonus (+3 from an item or a spell buff) versus a DC of 10) -- sometimes even a 1 won't fail to save.

  - Conversely, the only form of "automatic fail" is at the other end of the d20 rolling continuum.  An orc (without some kind of buff to a saving throw) can't roll the 21 he needs to save versus an Ancient Red Dragon's Frightful Presence.  (DC 21 versus a Wisdom saving throw ... no bonuses for a standard Orc).  His d20 roll isn't an automatic success, since he is not rolling an attack roll.

---

Death Saving Throws are an exception to the saving throw general rule.

Death Saving Throws (p. 76 Basic Rules)

> Whenever you start your turn with 0 hit points, you must make a
>   special saving throw, called a death saving ... Unlike other saving
>   throws, this one isn’t tied to any ability score.{snip}
>   **Rolling 1 or 20**. When you make a death saving throw and roll a 1 on
>   the d20, it counts as two failures. If you roll a 20 on the d20, you
>   regain 1 hit point.

Rules in the PHB are the same as in Basic Rules on this matter.

Comment: While mechanically a fail is a fail is a fail, from a role playing perspective a natural 1 or a 13 where a 14 is needed are golden opportunities to step aside from the mechanics of combat to describe the failure.

Comment: I feel it adds value to the answer to address it from a mechanical and role playing/story telling perspective.  Anyone could benefit from the reminder that just because things are mechanically the same, doesn't mean they need to play out the same at the table.

Comment: @Myles I added a brief comment on the description point.