# Does an savethrow-type attack cause critical damage for an unconscious creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, critical-hit, unconscious

The unconscious state description says

> **Any attack**    that    hits    the creature    is  a   critical    hit if   the    attacker    is  within  5   feet    of  the creature.

## Situation

Target creature is unconscious.
Attacker stands in 5 feet near it.
Attacker attack the target creature with savethrow-type attack of any kind. *Frostbite* cantrip for example.

## Question

Does this attack cause critical hit?

Comment: Related: [What counts as an attack?](/questions/71245), [Do saving throw based spells that do damage count as attacks?](/questions/65415)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### An attack is anything with an attack roll; saving throws do not have an attack roll so they are not attacks and do not interact with the unconscious rule.

The *Player's Handbook* states:

> If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you're making an attack roll, you're making an attack.

(See the question "[What counts as an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71245)"  for further evidence/help)

Since the *frostbite* cantrip involves a saving throw and not an attack roll it is not an attack and is not turned into a critical hit. In fact, saving throws cannot be critical hits at all because they don't even *hit*. Attacks are the only things that can either hit or miss, and so they are the only things that can critically hit or miss as well. This is explained in the question "[If you roll a 1 on a saving throw against a damage spell, do you take extra damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93831/)"