# If you roll a saving throw where you only take half damage on a success, do you reduce the damage even more on a Natural 20?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw

For context, my character just got pounded by flaming boulders. She is currently immune to fire for story reasons, so the fire damage is null. However, she has to make a dexterity saving throw against the bludgeoning damage. It deals 60 damage, however if she succeeds she takes half damage.

What happens if she rolls a natural 20?

I know the damage is halved because she did succeed, but are there any other reductions to damage because of her natural 20 roll?

(Note: For our house rules we play with the premise that a natural 20 is an automatic success and a natural 1 is an automatic fail)

Comment: Heavily related question here: [If you roll a 1 on a saving throw against a damage spell, do you take extra damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/93836/22566)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## No

Rules as written (and excluding house rules or specific rules for the effect that called for a save) there is no added effect from rolling a 20 on a saving throw (nor ability check).

The general description of saving throws in the *Player's Handbook* (p. 179) make no mention of rolling a 20 (nor a 1). However, the DMG section on ability checks and saving throws includes a subsection on Critical Success or Failure (p. 242) which says a DM can choose to have extraordinary outcomes on a roll of 1 or 20, but it opens with:

> Rolling a 20 or a 1 on an ability check or a saving throw doesn't normally have any special effect.

Comment: It still confuses me, coming off of 3.5e, that outside of an attack roll a 20 is just another number. Maybe someday I'll fully make the adjustment.

Comment: @Upper_Case-StopHarmingMonica Isn't 20 just another number outside of attack rolls in 3.5e?

Comment: @AndyM It's been a while, but as I recall natural 20s and 1s were automatic successes and failures, respectively, for skill checks as well in 3.5. My books are at home so I can't check right now, but if I'm mistaken then I'm even more mixed up on that (house) rule than I'd thought!

Comment: @Upper_Case-StopHarmingMonica In 3.5, natural 20s and 1s are automatic successes and failures for a) attack rolls and b) saving throws. Nothing else. For skill checks, they're just numbers.

Answer (score 12):

## No, you do not negate extra damage.

When making a saving throw, there is no such thing as a critical success nor critical failure. When you roll a 1 or a 20, simply add any relevant modifiers to that saving throw and use that total. The only exception to this is with a [death saving throw](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DeathSavingThrows) (see basic rules, p. 76):

> Whenever you start your turn with 0 hit points, you must make a special saving throw, called a death saving [...] Unlike other saving throws, this one isn’t tied to any ability score. [...]
>
> ***Rolling 1 or 20.*** When you make a death saving throw and roll a 1 on the d20, it counts as two failures. If you roll a 20 on the d20, you regain 1 hit point.

So, in your example, the character rolling a 1 on the Dexterity saving throw will take the full damage, unless she meets the DC with her Dexterity saving throw modifier. If she rolls a natural 20, she can still fail the saving throw if the DC is higher than the roll plus her bonuses.